# writing tfrecord with multithreading is not fast as expected

Tags: multithreading, performance, tensorflow, tfrecord

Tried to write tfrecord w/ and w/o multithreading, and found the speed difference is not much (w/ 4 threads: 434 seconds; w/o multithread 590 seconds). Not sure if I used it correctly. Is there any better way to write tfrecord faster?

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
import threading 
import time 


def generate_data(shape=[15,28,60,1]):
    return np.random.uniform(size=shape)


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def write_instances_to_tfrecord(tfrecord_file, filenames):
    tfrecord_writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_file)
    for i, filename in enumerate(filenames):
        curr_MFCC = generate_data()
        curr_MFCC_raw = curr_MFCC.tostring()
        curr_filename_raw = str(filename)+'-'+str(i)
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(
            feature={
            'MFCC': _bytes_feature(curr_MFCC_raw),
            'filename': _bytes_feature(curr_filename_raw)
            })
        )
        tfrecord_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    tfrecord_writer.close()


def test():
    threading_start = time.time()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = []
    for thread_index in xrange(4):
        args = (str(thread_index), range(200000))
        t = threading.Thread(target=write_instances_to_tfrecord, args=args)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    coord.join(threads)
    print 'w/ threading takes', time.time()-threading_start

    start = time.time()
    write_instances_to_tfrecord('5', range(800000))
    print 'w/o threading takes', time.time()-start

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 3):

When using python threading, due to the GIL restriction in the cPython implementation, the CPU utilization will be capped at 1 core. No matter how many threads you add, you will not see a speed up.

A simple solution in your case would be to use the `multiprocessing` module.
The code is almost exactly the same as what you have, just switch threads to processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
processes = []
for thread_index in xrange(4):
    args = (str(thread_index), range(200000))
    p = Process(target=write_instances_to_tfrecord, args=args)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
coord.join(processes)
```

I tested this on my own tfrecord writer code, and got a linear scaling speedup. Total number of processes is limited by memory.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use Tensorflow computation graph to take advantage of multithreading since each session and graph can be run in different threads. With computation graph, it's about 40 times faster.